# Generate a zip from a Maven multi module project where each module must be package in other zips

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

I Have a Multi Module Maven project where each module will be a zip file, what I want is to create a new zip that package the othe zip modules, is it possible?

For example:

1. Project 1 - Maven generates a zip that package the other 2 zips

   - Project 2 - Maven generates a Zip in the target directory
   - Project 3 - Maven generates a Zip in the target directory

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/assembly-of-assemblies

Comment: It doesn't work, I already have 2 zips I'd just like to put then inside another

Comment: The example project exactly does this. Please show you pom files or put an example project on github...